# How to set ngModel in directive template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjL9yvea/).
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div my-rd name="gender" value="male" model="gender"></div>
        <div my-rd name="gender" value="female" model="gender"></div>
        <p>Your choice is: {{gender}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("myRd", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            name: "@",
            value: "@",
            model: "="
        },
        template: "<input name='{{name}}' ng-model='model' value='{{value}}' checked type='radio' />{{value}}"
    }
})
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

})
```

I created a directive which can generate a custom radio button with custom attributes. The problem is I can't set ng-model name correctly and the "checked" property doesn't work as well.
Please give me a hand, many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by can't set ng-model name correctly ? 
And checked is used mainly for checkbox.

Comment: I guess, it should be ng-checked='{{model}}'. That sets the value to the model value, if that's what you wish to achieve.

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014303/updating-ng-model-within-a-directive-that-uses-a-template)

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working fine. ng-model also working fine. When check any radio I get Your Choice is: male, and Your Choice is:female.

Comment: I have model: '=' in my scope, but the ng-model in directive always showed "model". If I wrote <div my-rd model="test">, the ng-model in directive should be ng-model="test". What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the naming of your attribute is incorrect? If so `=` means it must have the same name as the scope property.

Answer (score 1):

You use the shorthand syntax `=` that means the attribute name is the same as the value you want to bind to inside the directive's scope.

If the declaration is `<div my-rd foo="test">` then you have to specify in your directive

```
model: "=foo" //It tells $compile to bind to the foo attribute.
```

Here in your directive you can access the value

```
//directive will know only the property inside scope:{'your_propery': value}    
//to access the value inside directive {{your_propery}}
scope.model //{{model}}
```

And in your controller you can access the value

```
$scope.test //{{test }}
```

[More details](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)