# Why formatters does not work with isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why formatters does not work with isolated scope? Is this angular bug or I am doing something wrong?

This contains isolates scope and does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/YbdXQ/56/

```
 restrict: 'A',
 scope:{},
 link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
          console.log("In formatters" + modelValue);
         return $filter('date')(modelValue);
     });
```

This does not contain isolated and scope works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YbdXQ/57/

```
 restrict: 'A',
 link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
          console.log("In formatters" + modelValue);
         return $filter('date')(modelValue);
     });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with formatters, but rather the fact that `ngModel` no longer has access to the value you're trying to pass it. When you're creating an isolate scope, `myDate` is no longer available to the `ngModel` directive (since you've created a new scope--an isolate scope--that doesn't have `myDate` on it). As proof, here's a [not-so-useful example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbdXQ/78/) that set's `myDate` on the scope based on what's passed in to the `ngModel` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/YbdXQ/78/

[angular/angular.js#1069](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1069), "One directive's isolation scope isolates other directives on the same element," talks about this very problem:

> For example, notice how my custom directive is preventing ng-model from working

You may also be interested in [this StackOverflow question, "ngModel and component with isolated scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope).