# Why does ng-style not work on the same element as a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to apply the ng-style attribute on a custom directive tag, kind of like so:

```
<my-directive ng-style="myStyle"></my-directive>
```

Inside the controller I have:

```
$scope.myStyle = {
    "background": "red"
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though. When I inspect the HTML 'MyStyle' does not get rendered. When I apply the same ng-style tag on a regular div it does render properly.

Why doesn't ng-style work on custom directive tags?

Comment: seems file [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z56yH/2/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your directive likely defines an isolate scope: `scope: { ... }`.  In that case, all directives defined on that element will use the isolate scope.  Therefore, ng-style will look for property `myStyle` on the isolate scope, which doesn't exist.

[image]

Above, gray lines show $parents, dashed lines show prototypal inheritance.
Scope 004 is your isolate scope.  Scope 003 is your controller scope.  ng-style will look for `myStyle` in scope 004, not find it, then it will follow the dashed line and look for it in Scope, and not find it there either.

Normally you don't want to use directives that create an isolate scope along with other directives on the same element.  You have a few options:

1. use `scope: true` instead of an isolate scope in your directive.  Then when ng-style looks for `myStyle` in scope 004 and doesn't find it, it will then follow the dashed line (in the picture below) and find it in the parent scope:
   [image]
2. use `ng-style="$parent.myStyle"` in your HTML to access the `myStyle` property in the parent scope (i.e., follow the gray line in the first picture).

Comment: What a thorough answer. Very nice!

Comment: Mark, if you're not preparing a book about Angular, than you should.

Comment: Your hunch was exactly the issue I was facing. Thanks for such a detailed answer. Now I just need to figure out which solution is the best for me. My directive represents a reusable 'widget' and my understanding is that it is good practice for such directives to have isolated scope. I'm also considering wrapping my directive in a div and applying the ng-style to this div.

Comment: @sthomps, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14914798/215945) by Josh might help you decide which kind of scope is appropriate for your directive.

Comment: Is there a good solution if I want the directive's style method to be called, without interfacing to the controller?