# Custom directive in ng-repeat: Why does ng-style not apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive `myItems` that is rendering a list of items using another directive `myItem` via `ng-repeat`:

```
app.directive('myItems', function() {
    return {
        scope:{items:"="},
        restrict:"E",
        template:"<div my-item ng-repeat='item in items'></div>"
    };
});
```

Each item contains information (such as a color) that has be used for styling the elements.  This works fine so far if I use the templating approach:

```
app.directive('myItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        template:"<div ng-style='{color:item.color}'>myItem: {{item.name}}</div>",
        replace:true
    };
});
```

To support more involved features, I now want to rebuild the same functionality if `my-item` by manually creating all the needed stuff including the ng-style:

```
app.directive('myItem', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        compile: function(element) {
            element.removeAttr('my-item');
            element.text('myItem: {{item.name}}');
            element.attr('ng-style', '{color:item.color}');    // Why does it have no effect?

            var compileElement = $compile(element);
            return function link(scope, elem, attr) {
                compileElement(scope);    // Why does binding with {{item.name}} even work without this statement?
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Interestingly enough databinding using `{{item.name}}` works while `ng-style` does not.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muL9k8dp/7/) showing both approaches described above.

I am aware of the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15423955/571213). But I think it does not apply here since I have no explicit statements about the scope of the `my-item` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a catch with the compile function: it is called for the directives of an element, after Angular has "parsed" that element. This means that *any directive added from the code of the `compile()` function to the element containing the directive being compiled **will not be parsed by Angular**!* This is why `element.attr('ng-style', '{color:item.color}');` is disregarded.

On the other hand, the `compileElement(scope);` is superfluous; any DOM manipulation done **inside** the element containing the directive being compiled, **will be parsed by Angular**.

What can you do? Your situation is easy, it is a trivial DOM manipulation to add the style with a watch (even without the watch, if you do not expect the color to change):

```
return function link(scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.$watch('item.color', function(newval) {
        elem.css('color', newval);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I have hoped to be able to stick to an imperative way of databinding, I understand the reasoning and will go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `compileElement` does compile the ng-style element, but because `$compile` was called before the element was fully constructed, calling `compileElement` worked on a invalid version of the element and ng-style didn't changed the color.

So you can move the `$compile` inside the link function:

```
var compileElement = $compile(elem);
compileElement(scope);
```

But then it also compiles again the ng-repeat directive which is no good. So you need to remove that attribute as well:

```
element.removeAttr('ng-repeat');
```

Check [this plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/atswo4p9/).