# How to use ng-show on a directive that has an isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I use like this:

```
<dir model="data"></dir>
```

The directive has an isolated scope.

```
scope :{
  model:'='
}
```

Now I'm trying to use `ng-show` on that directive using another attribute of my page's $scope, like this:

```
<dir ng-show="show" model="data"></dir>
```

But it's not working because the directive is trying to find the `show` attribute on its own scope.

I don't want the directive to know about the fact that its container might choose to hide it.

The workaround I found is to wrap the directive in a `<div>` and apply `ng-show` on that element, but I don't like the extra element this forces me to use:

```
<div ng-show="show" >
  <dir model="data"></dir>    
</div>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3MkWfl5mHssUeh3zXiR?p=preview

Comment: Did you try changing the priority of your directive to be before/after `ngShow`?

Comment: @r3m0t: Priority does not seem to affect this. I tried -10000 and 10000.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could consider migrating to Angular 1.2 or higher. [The isolate scope is now only exposed to directives with a scope property](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#isolate-scope-only-exposed-to-directives-with-property). This means the ng-show is not influenced by your directive anymore and you can write it exactly like you tried to do it in the first place:

```
<dir ng-show="show" model="data"></dir>
```

@Angular-Developers: Great work, guys!

Comment: It works indeed. See same plnkr w/ 1.2 in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ARAqyErwwkINvIDn1TwF?p=preview

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** This answer applies to Angular releases prior to 1.2.  See @lex82's answer for Angular 1.2.

Because your `dir` directive creates an isolate scope, all directives defined on the same element (`dir` in this case) will use that isolate scope.  This is why `ng-show` looks for property `show` on the isolate scope, rather than on the parent scope.

If your `dir` directive is truly a [standalone/self-contained/reusable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc), and therefore it should use an isolate scope, your wrapping solution is probably best (better than using `$parent`, IMO) because such directives should normally not be used with other directives on the same element (or you get exactly this kind of problem).

If your directive doesn't need an isolate scope, your problem goes away.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following into the link function solves the problem. It's an extra step for the component creator, but makes the component more intuitive.

```
function link($scope, $element, attr, ctrl) {

    if (attr.hasOwnProperty("ngShow")) {
        function ngShow() {
            if ($scope.ngShow === true) {
                $element.show();
            }
            else if($scope.ngShow === false) {
                $element.hide();
            }
        }
        $scope.$watch("ngShow", ngShow);
        setTimeout(ngShow, 0);
    }
    //... more in the link function
}
```

You'll also need to setup scope bindings for ngShow

```
scope: {
    ngShow: "="
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$parent` for the parent scope like this:

```
<dir ng-show="$parent.show" model="data"></dir>
```

**Disclaimer**

I think that this is the precise answer to your question but I admit that it is not perfect from an aesthetical point of view. However, wrapping the `<div>` isn't very nice either. I think one can justify it because from the other parameter passed to the isolate scope, it can be seen that the directive actually has an isolate scope. On the other hand, I have to acknowledge that i regularly forget the $parent in the first place and then wonder why it is not working.

It would certainly be clearer to add an additional attribute `is-visible="expression"` and insert the `ng-show` internally. But you stated in your question that you tried to avoid this solution.

***Update:*** *Won't work in Angular 1.2 or higher.*