# Angular directive restrict E breaks code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a followup to this question. I have the same setup:

[Angular scope is shared for all modules and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980337/angular-scope-is-shared-for-all-modules-and-controllers)

So root module, controllers and directives. Now to the question:

I have a service, that has this written inside:

```
firstModule.factory("firstService", function () {
   return {   
       $('.mainitems').click(function () {               
            alert("hi")
        });
   };
});
```

And a directive, that is nested inside other directive:

```
    secondModule.directive("secondDirective", function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "./myurl",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, controller) {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I have the line : `restrict: "E"`, the click function does not work, but when I remove it, then it works.

Any idea why this may be the problem? It's a strange thing, after a day of debugging I found the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact manage dom manipulation in factory is a bad pattern ! All DOM manipulation have to be place in directive so for a click it's `ng-click`

For example :

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-click="click()"></div>
</div>
```

Where click() is a function fo your scope. So you have your controller like this :

```
secondModule.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.click = function(){
      //do what you want
    };

});
```

When you'll click on your div it will call the click function in your controller

Your directive should be :

```
secondModule.directive("secondDirective", function () {
return {
    template: "<div ng-click='click()'><a>Click here</a></div>",
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    link: function (tElement, tAttrs, controller) {
    }
}
});
```

And you html like that :

```
<second-directive></second-directive>
```

Working plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/DmkQTp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

When you provide `restrict: "E"` (element) as a configuration option `ng` will expect a custom tag like: `<second-directive></second-directive>` for this directive to be applied.
When you remove it, it defaults to `"A"` (attribute), which may be what you are using as declaration to apply this directive.