# Multiple AngularJS directives with different scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I have a two popup directives on the same page. The problem is when I click on one they both pop up.

How can I isolate each scope from each other so only the popup that's clicked pops up?

HTML

```xml
<popup class="popup">
  <trigger>
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()">Show Popup</a>
  </trigger>
  <pop>
   I popped up
  </pop>
</popup>

<popup class="popup">
  <trigger>
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()">Show Popup</a>
  </trigger>
  <pop>
   I popped up too
  </pop>
</popup>
```

popup.js

```js
angular.module('sembaApp')
  .directive('popup', function () {
    return {
        restrict:  'E',
        replace:    true,
      transclude: true,
      template:   '<div data-ng-transclude></div>',
      controller: function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.popup = false;
        $scope.showPopup = function() {
          $scope.popup = !$scope.popup;
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('trigger', function () {
    return {
        require: '^popup',
        restrict:  'E',
        replace:    true,
      transclude: true,
      template:   '<div data-ng-transclude></div>',
    }
  })
  .directive('pop', function () {
    return {
        require: '^popup',
        restrict:  'E',
        replace:    true,
      transclude: true,
      template:   '<aside data-ng-transclude data-ng-show="popup"> yay</aside>'      
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a better idea to simplify the directives so the scopes will be easy to handle.

```
<div ng-app="sembaApp" ng-init="popup1=false;popup2=false;">
    <popup class="popup" ng-model="popup1">
        <pop data-ng-show="popup1">I popped up</pop>
    </popup>
    <popup class="popup" ng-model="popup2">
        <pop data-ng-show="popup2">I popped up too</pop>
    </popup>
</div>

angular.module('sembaApp', [])
    .directive('popup', function () {
    return {
        scope:{
            ngModel: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div data-ng-transclude><a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()">Show Popup</a></div>',
        link: function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.showPopup = function () {
                console.log($scope.ngModel);
                $scope.ngModel = !$scope.ngModel;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEtZu/)**</kbd>

Comment: yep this works too. The only thing is I don't like using ng-init as it's logic in my view.

Comment: Ok, you can move that initialization logic to the controller. I just wanted to demo the code and simplify a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure each of your directive as a different scope, you could add a `scope : true` to the object returned by your directive function.

You should definitely check out the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) ("Writing directives (long version)"), it explains the power of the scope attribute, how to isolate the scope, bind arguments, etc...

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc) provides an even better explanation.

Comment: scope:true doesn't work as it isolates $scope.popup from the pop directive. The documentation is down at the moment so will read your link.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing $scope.popup to this.popup

```
  <popup class="popup"> 
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()">Show Popup</a>
    <pop> 
      I popped up
    </pop>
  </popup>

  controller: function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    this.popup = false;
    $scope.showPopup = function() {
      this.popup = !this.popup;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is working? This doesn't make too much sense since the 2nd `this.popup` is in a closure and it is definitely different from the first `this.popup`.

Comment: Oh I also removed the trigger     `<popup class="popup">
            <a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()">Show Popup</a>
          <pop>
            I popped up
          </pop>
        </popup>`

Comment: Yes the first this.popup can be removed

Comment: Also can further simplify the the html by making the directive an attribute `<a href="#" data-ng-click="showPopup()" popup class="popup">Show Popup <pop>I popped up </pop> </a>`