# AngularJS Custom Directive Two Way Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have an AngularJS directive without a template and I want it to set a property on the current scope, what is the best way to do it?

For example, a directive that counts button clicks:

```
<button twoway="counter">Click Me</button>
<p>Click Count: {{ counter }}</p>
```

With a directive that assigns the click count to the expression in the two way attribute:

```
.directive('twoway', [
'$parse',
  function($parse) {
    return {
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('click', function() {
          var current = scope.$eval(attrs.twoway) || 0;
          $parse(attrs.twoway).assign(scope, ++current);
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Is there a better way to do this?  From what I've read, an isolated scope would be overkill, but do I need a child scope?  And is there a cleaner way to write back to a scope variable defined in the directive attribute other than using `$parse`.  I just feel like I'm making this too difficult.

Full Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DMLJCz?p=preview).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Or code architecture. I think it's a good question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Why is an isolate scope overkill? its pretty useful for exactly this kind of thing:

```
  scope: {
     "twoway": "=" // two way binding
  },
```

This is a pretty idiomatic angular solution to this problem, so this is what I'd stick with.

Comment: Doug T.  I was going off of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc), but I probably only understood a quarter of it.

Comment: The critical addition to this answer is that the variable that you pass into this directive, e.g. `counter`, **must** be an object, e.g. `obj.counter` otherwise you won't get a proper reference to update the parent scope.

Answer (score 25):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned `ng-model`, the default directive for doing two-data binding. Maybe it's not so well known, but the linking function has a fourth parameter:

```
angular.module('directive-binding', [])
  .directive('twoway', 
      function() {
        return {
          require: '?ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
              var counter = ngModel.$viewValue ? ngModel.$viewValue : 0
              ngModel.$setViewValue(++counter);
              scope.$apply();
            });
          }
        };
      }
    );
```

On your view

```
<button twoway ng-model="counter">Click Me</button>
<p>Click Count: {{ counter }}</p>
```

The fourth parameter is an API for the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController), which has many uses for handling (parsing and formatting, for instance) and sharing data between a directive and a scope.

Here's the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bwTSfs?p=preview).

Comment: I was hoping to model the directive syntax after something like ngshow/nghide that takes the model property directly in its attribute value.  I appreciate the implementation using ngModel though -- its something I haven't explored to deeply yet.

Comment: Then go for isolate scope, see Doug's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely simplify it a bit like this without using `$parse`

```
angular.module('directive-binding', []).directive('twoway', [function () {
    return {
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function () {
                scope[attrs.twoway] = scope[attrs.twoway] == null ? 1 : scope[attrs.twoway] + 1;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you use a "nested" object in your model.  For example, if I used "counter.val" instead of "counter", this doesn't seem to work.  [Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AvTTgW?p=preview) -- my JS skills are not the best, so I may have missed something though.

Comment: @DavidFaivre You need to initialize it in the controller like `$scope.counter={}; $scope.counter.val = 0`

Comment: if you're interested, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) on accessing "nested" objects by string.  That's the underlying issue with this solution -- that you'd have to write some sort of parser.  The $parser service, or the nested scope mapping, handles that for us in the Angular world.

Comment: @DavidFaivre You didn't mention you want to use nested object in your original question. When you ask question, make sure you ask something clear.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to apply two way binding is to use directive components. Here is my solution. It allows use of ng-repeat and expandable data binding.

[View Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jLafvuAGVsq5SxCElPUL?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>  
    Data: {{data}}
    <hr>
    <mydirective name='data[0]'></mydirective>
    <hr>
    <mydirective name='data[1]'></mydirective>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.data[0] = 'Marco';
  $scope.data[1] = 'Billy';
});
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {name: '='},
        template: "<div>Your name is : {{name}}</div>"+
        "Change your name : <input type='text' ng-model='name' />"
    };
});
```

In the case of the counter, it can be done using the same method.

Comment: how can i access **data[1]**  in my directive controller to make **HTTP get** call

Comment: You can add `{controller : myDirectivecontroller}` to your directive as part of the return object, and have it manipulate your data in the directive controller. I suggest keeping all RESTful requests in a Service, and have the Service referenced in the controller, like this:

`function myDirectivecontroller(ServiceName) {
   var ctrl = this;
   ...
}`

Comment: @n.bharath I wrote this out with the use of components: http://plnkr.co/edit/4wOdA3OYkxS9vXAWfSxZ?p=preview

Comment: From  **<my-component name='data.names[0]'></my-component>** access **name** in controller based on **name** value then do **http get** call and bind response to **template**  ** "<div>Your name is : {{$ctrl.response }}</div>"**

Answer (score 0):

Change template to:

```
<button twoway bind="counter">Click Me</button>
<p>Click Count: {{ counter.val }}</p>
```

and directive to:

```
.directive('twoway',
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                localValue: '=?bind'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.localValue = {
                    val: 0
                };
                elem.on('click', function() {
                    scope.localValue.val = scope.localValue.val + 1;
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is an answer to the question?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.