# Give angular directive a model name to access it's scope in the parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access the isolated scope of a directive by using the model attribute on it's element when I use it in the HTML. Eg.

```
<div controller="parent">
    <hello-world data-ng-model="hw"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</div>
```

The controller for the parent:

```
function($scope){
  $scope.submit = function(){
    alert($scope.hw.t);
  }
};
```

The directive for the hello-world:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return { 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.t = 'test';
    }, 
    replace: true, 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: {}, 
    template: '<h5>Hello world {{t}}</h4>'
  };
});
```

t is defined in the isolated scope, because it is displayed correctly. However, when I click the submit button, I get an error because hw is undefined. (Because the hello-world scope isn't being assigned to the 'hw' scope variable of the parent. How can I let hw be defined as the scope of the hello-world directive? My use case is to make a date picker that exposes the date picked through it's scope. Like

```
<date-picker ng-model="date1"/>
<date-picker ng-model="date2"/>
```

In the directive's scope, I would ensure that the month, year, etc. are defined. Then in the parent controller, I can use `$scope.date1.month` and similar to access the date picked.

Comment: can you post a plnkr of your issue please..

Comment: Indeed, `hw` is firstly undefined in `parent` controller's scope. You should either check if `$scope.hw` is defined before accessing it or give it a default value `$scope.hw = {t: 'Hello world'};`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JhSnh8cx11gP7Irq9H2J?p=preview

Comment: @blint, I know how to give a default value to a model that is an object, like that. But the difference is that I want the default (and the value in general) to be assigned by the hello world directive.

Comment: It sounds like you need to setup two-way binding for some scope values between your parent controller and directives instead of using ng-model e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882428/angularjs-custom-directive-two-way-binding Or am I misunderstanding something? Your plunkr does not encapsulate the code you've provided on SO.

Comment: just ran in to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following to your comments, it seems you need to make custom validateable elements using *ngModel*.

According to [`ngModel`'s documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), this can be done by using manually `ngModelController`. The following page should contain all the information you need about that (look at `script.js` in the example): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Good luck.

[An example of a directive that works with ngModel](http://plnkr.co/edit/JhSnh8cx11gP7Irq9H2J?p=info)

Comment: +0.5 for the `Good luck.` :)

Comment: That was it. Not exactly, as it doesn't just assign the inner scope to the model, I wouldn't be surprised if such a construct doesn't even exist. I was underestimating the inner complexity of a model (or maybe overestimating it's universality).

Comment: Indeed you can't just send your ngModel through your directive. In fact, adding the `ng-model` to your custom element will decorate your directive and will instantiate a separate `ngModelController` controller. If you need to combine the functionnalities, you have to do some custom work in order to use the instantiated `ngModelController`. As mentionned by ExpertSystem, `Good luck` was part of the answer ;)