# Show Variables on Markup Using Angular Directive With Isolate Scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with an isolate scope and its own controller.  I'd like to pass a value from the parent scope and print out its value onto the markup.  I thought I could merely pass it like this:

```
scope: {
    isoProp: '='
}
```

I set up watches on the link and controller, so I do see the value being passed properly.  However, I don't know how to use that value on the markup itself.

I've set up a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wUfuPadiW5Zz1r4klWV5) to illustrate my issue.  On line 17 in index.html, I was expecting `{{dirCtrl.isoProp}}` or `{{isoProp}}` to print out the value that I passed in, but they don't seem to.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using the isolate scope in the right way.  It is usually (always?) used with it's own template.  See the related question and answer for [When writing a directive, how do I decide if a need no new scope, a new child scope, or a new isolate scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the markup to `template` like this:

```
template: '{{isoProp}}'
```