# How would I share scope between an angular controller and a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvYSu/36/).

What I expect to happen is that a select list is displayed and when one of the options is selected the word `true` or `false` is displayed on this line of code:

`<span data-ng-bind="cardType.transactionFee"></span>`

The `$watch` part of it is working as the alert that says `hey, cardType has changed!` is displayed whenever the card type changes.

How can I pass the changed values to the `directive`?

```
.controller('AddCreditCardChargeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.creditCards = [
      { name: 'VISA DEBIT/DELTA', value: 'DEL', transactionFee: false},
      { name: 'VISA CREDIT', value: 'VIS', transactionFee: true },
      { name: 'MASTERCARD CREDIT', value: 'MSC', transactionFee: true },
      { name: 'MASTERCARD DEBIT', value: 'MCD', transactionFee: false },
      { name: 'MAESTRO', value: 'MAE', transactionFee: false },
      { name: 'SWITCH', value: 'SWI', transactionFee: false },
      { name: 'VISA ELECTRON', value: 'ELC', transactionFee: false },
      { name: 'SOLO', value: 'SOL', transactionFee: false }
  ];

    $scope.selectAction = function() {
       alert($scope.creditCardModel);
       alert(hasTransFee($scope.creditCardModel));
       $scope.cardType=hasTransFee($scope.creditCardModel);
      // console.log(cardType.name)
      // console.log(cardType.transactionFee)
       console.log('watch')
       $scope.$watch("cardType.transactionFee", function() {
                    alert('hey, cardType has changed!');
         });
    }

  var hasTransFee = function(cardType) 
  {
   for (var i=0; i < $scope.creditCards.length; i++) {
      if($scope.creditCards[i].value==cardType && $scope.creditCards[i].transactionFee == true){
       return true;   
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}])

.directive('bhtDiscountPrice',['BasketFactory',
function(BasketFactory){
return{
    restrict:'EA',
    scope:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){},

    template:'<span data-ng-bind="cardType.transactionFee"></span>'
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

`scope: false`, so no new scope at all,thus you will be share scope with controller

### Note

for best way of using scope when you write custom directive please have a look [When writing a directive in AngularJS, how do I decide if I need no new scope, a new child scope, or a new isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc)

### Edit:

try this ,without using `link` function

```
 .directive('bhtDiscountPrice',['BasketFactory',
function(BasketFactory){
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        template:'<span data-ng-bind="cardType.transactionFee"></span>'
      };
    });
```

Comment: I tried that and no change unfortunately.  I'll check out that link thank you :)

Comment: check update please,using jsfiddle that you give i maked it work