# Scopeless directives - how to get data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using scopeless directives (https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#directives-and-controlleras).

```
<directive1>
    <directive2></directive2>
</directive2>
```

In outer `directive1` I've got `controllerAS: 'vm'` with `var vm=this; vm.test="test from directive1"` in it.

Inner `directive2` has `scope: false, controllerAs: 'vm2', bindToController:true` 
How from `directive2` get `directive1` `vm.test` data? I want to use it in controller - not HTML view

Comment: It does not mean it is scopeless, it just uses parent scope. You can get it via `scope.vm` itself

Comment: I mean that I don't want to use `$scope`. Read this https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controlleras-view-syntax

Comment: Problem is with your design... Why does your directive has a hidden dependency on parent controller, if so then just use require in your directive.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc/14914798#14914798) on how to scope your directive. trying to access it with your specific case is an X/Y problem due to design issue, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do with

```
var vm = this
```

is a local variable to directive 1's JS scope (not angular's $scope object). Directive2 will never have access to it. To provide access you will have to attache vm to directive one's scope. Then it will be accessible to the nested directive two's $scope.

Like this in directive one

```
$scope.vm = this; // This will work
$scope.vm.test = 'test from directive1 scope';
```

Like this in directive two

```
controller: function ($scope) {
  console.log($scope.vm.test) // this will work for you
```

Here is a working jsFiddle example.

[working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/5ew48u8b/1/)

Comment: OP is using controllerAs syntax, so vm/vm2 aliases are not some local variable it is a property on the scope already.

Comment: But I don't want to use `$scope` at all: read this https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controlleras-view-syntax

Comment: Perhaps you can use the jsFiddle I provided and test your theory? I simply can't call $scope.vm or scope.vm in directive2 and get the value. What do you propose in a working jsFiddle example?

Comment: Ah, I see your example, thank you for posting it for clarification.