# Why does the parent scope break when nesting a directive using controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web application has several pages who have their own controller. Inside these pages I use directives who also have a controller. All controllers use the controllerAs syntax and they are all set as `vm`. According to [this](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) article this should work. However, I'm having trouble making it work in combination with a directive. In this codepen I have reproduced a similar situation:

http://codepen.io/csteur/pen/LGEdLy

In this example the parent scope is also broken because of the nested directive. Can anyone explain why this happens or how this can be changed to make it work?

Comment: Its working fine. What is the problem ?

Comment: @VVK The vm.title of the mainController is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to isolat your contoller with the directory

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'AngularJS Nested Controller Example';
});

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('nestedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {}, 
    controller: 'nestedDirectiveController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template:'<div> {{vm.message}} </div>'
  };
});

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('nestedDirectiveController', nestedDirectiveController);

function nestedDirectiveController() {
  var vm = this;
  this.message = "hoi";
}
```

Check the codepen if you would like:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeYxQg

Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/angularjs-when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a) for more information

Comment: I got it to work by adding `scope: {}` line. I'm not really sure what you mean by 'share with the directory' but I guess the link you provide explains this. Thanks for the quick reply @Arvaan

Answer (score 0):

When you define `var vm = this;` inside `nestedDirectiveController`, the scope of `vm` is limited to  `nestedDirectiveController` only.

Since you directive has isolated scope and your template uses this `nestedDirectiveController` function to evaluate the expression, it gets title value `null` and we see no title.

If you want shared scope then you can provide  `scope : true` config in your directive. So that the directive gets its own scope that inherits prototypically from the parent scope.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('nestedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true, 
    controller: 'nestedDirectiveController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template:'<div> {{vm.message}} </div>'
  };
});
```

**[See Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPaLGp)**