# ng-change and ng-focus not working in custom input directive

Tags: angularjs, events, bind

I'm working on customize a input directive which including a label. I tried several days and refer to some articles. 
The only problem is that except ng-change, ng-blur and ng-focus, all the other event work. https://jsfiddle.net/luneyq/mw3oz2pr/
Of course I can bind these three event manually myself and they can work as https://jsfiddle.net/luneyq/bp7f3z1o/

But I really don't know why ng-change, ng-blur and ng-focus don't work. Is there any special on these three event?
Anyone can help on this?

My codes are as below:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <my-input type="number" name="valueNumber1" ng-model="obj.valueNumber1" label="Age" ng-click="log('click')" ng-change="log('change')" ng-blur="log('blur')" ng-focus="log('focus')" ng-mouseleave="log('mouseleave')"></my-input>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $window){
    $scope.obj = {valueNumber1: 10};
    $scope.log = function(text) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text + ':' + $scope.obj.valueNumber1 + "<br>" + document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
    };
});

app.directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
        require:  '^ngModel',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            name: '@name',
            label: '@label'
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        priority: 10,
        template: '<div>' +
        '<label for="{{ name }}">{{label}}</label>' +
        '<input id="{{ name }}" ng-model="ngModel" />' +
        '</div>',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var tInput = tElement.find('input');
            // Move the attributed given to 'custom-input' to the real input field
            angular.forEach(tAttrs, function(value, key) {
                if (key.charAt(0) == '$')
                    return;
                tInput.attr(key, value);
            });
            tElement.replaceWith('<div class="cbay-input-div">' + tElement.html() + '</div>');
            return;
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble to go through, just to add a label to an input. Why not just do it the old fashioned way?

Comment: In your code `click` and `mouseleave` are applied to the `DIV` in the directive view. `change`, `focus` and `blur` events exist for form elements only. Hence they handlers should be set to the `input` element (not to the `DIV`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that compilation/transclusion/replace don't work the way you think they work (not sure where you made an incorrect assumption).

What is wrong with your code:

1). You are using incorrect attribute name: you should use `tInput.attr(tAttrs.$attr[key], value);` instead of `tInput.attr(key, value);`.

2). All the directives specified at `my-input` are compiled and linked despite your changes to the `tElement` in `compile` function. Proof is here - https://jsfiddle.net/fyuz3auc/3/, take a look at the `myTest` directive and its output in console: it is still applied to the `myInput` despite any of your effort.

3). You specified `scope` for your directive. Thus it has an isolated scope, thus anything you've compiled inside it has no access to `log` function of `MainController`, that's why your `log`s aren't working. Here is the fiddle proving that: https://jsfiddle.net/m5tba2mf/1/ (take a look at `$scope.log = $scope.$parent.log` in `link` function returned from `compile`).

In order to solve the second issue I suggest you to try alternative approach - I am using this at my project, and like it very much. The idea is to use `terminal` in conjunction with extremely high priority and `$compile`. Here is the updated fiddle, I think it is pretty straightforward what I do there: https://jsfiddle.net/uoat55sj/1/.

Comment: I appreciated your explaination. I still have two more questions: 1) in my original code, I neither used $scope.log = $scope.$parent.log nor default scope(false) :  https://jsfiddle.net/luneyq/mw3oz2pr/, but ng-click and some other event work, why?    2) as to the approach you suggested and used in your project which use the default scope(false),  I read somewhere mentioned that the default false scope is not recommended in directive. Is there any bad influence using this approach?

Comment: 1). They worked at the top-level element of your directive, that's what I was trying to show in (2) - remove all of your code from `compile` - they will still work: https://jsfiddle.net/0znsL231/

Comment: 2). Unless you provide me a link, I can't really answer that - I guess you misunderstood something. In your case it should be completely correct to use inherited scope: https://jsfiddle.net/osrgp29p/ - everything works. You can read some info regarding different types of scopes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/angularjs-when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a

Comment: one more question, why the attribute ngModel is needed as mandatory? In your code: if (!tAttrs.ngModel) {
                 throw new Error("ngModel is required!");
                }

Comment: I guess I wrote it during some intermediate  change, disregard that piece.