# being notified when ng-if is adding/removing element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

I use ng-if to add/remove a typehead input for inline edition purpose.
the ng-if value is updated by a "edit" button

So, what is the best or recommended way to give focus to the text input, once it's added to the dom ?

thanks

Lionel

Comment: sorry , i have a misunderstanding to ng-focus. It's a event handler lik ng-click. I will delete my anwser.

Comment: it seems that you need to add a directive yourself to trigger DOM focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of AngularJS doesn't have a focus directive.

But you can refer
[Input autofocus attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859266/input-autofocus-attribute)

And create you own directive for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Following Chen-Tsu Lin comment, here is a small directive for focusing element once they're added (used with ng-if)

```
module.directive('inputFocus',['$timeout', function($timeout){
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem){
      $timeout(function(){
        elem[0].focus();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

to use it:

```
<input type="text" input-focus ng-if="isShown"  />
```

and here is the JsBin http://jsbin.com/texujona/5/