# AngularJS - Add attribute at runtime

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app. I'm trying to add the autofocus attribute to an element at runtime. The reason I want to do this is so I can set this attribute on one of several elements. How do you add an HTML attribute to an element via an AngularJS directive?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input autofocus attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859266/input-autofocus-attribute)

Comment: I see that. However, I don't like this approach. In my opinion it dirtys up the $scope. With this approach, I have to have a variable for each control. I'm trying to create a directive that allows me to give the ID of a control at the form level. I will then find that control and I'd like to set the autofocus attribute on that control.

Comment: firstly, what the reason to add `autofocus` to several elements? Do you want to add it by elements's id or by some jQuery selector?

Comment: I do NOT want several elements to have autofocus. Instead, I want to find an element within the form element and add autofocus to that element. I want to add autofocus to an element by ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $set method on the `$compile.directive.Attributes` object. See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$set). This will create a new attribute which AngularJS will recognize. Remember to use the normalized (camelCase) version of the attribute. You can do it in the link function of your directive.

Answer (score 0):

That's directive:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('ng').directive('dynamicAutoFocus', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.dynamicAutoFocus, function(id){

          if(angular.isDefined(id)){
            var target = document.getElementById(id);
            if(target){
              target.focus();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
})();
```

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/y2DKd8/preview)