# How to shift focus to next input type in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have four input text box to enter credit card no. I want to shift focus to next input type. I can do this normal Jquery way. But I want to do in angular way. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24455266/360171

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks Yuriy and Yagiz. But I want to shift focus to next input box only when first input box has four digits and then only it should shift focus to next input field.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using jquery way.Did not find much options in angular.