# ios 10 autofocus not focusing input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

When i'm running an application on Desktop or Android device, input focus is working fine. But it's not working in ios 10 Safari. I am using angularjs.

```
$timeout(function () {
  var input = $element.find('.my-input-box')[0];
  input.focus();
}, 500);
```

Comment: $timeout(function () {
      $('#someID').focus();
    }, 500);   try this

Comment: check that your input element is in DOM or NOT ?

Comment: It's in DOM that's why working on Desktop and Android

Comment: it might be in DOM in less than 500ms on Desktop and Android, but not on iOS...

Comment: It also don't work when time out is 2000

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: If there isn't any error it may be some other element gets focus after `input.focus()` .

Comment: What do you get on `console.log(input)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using angularjs, you should definitely try finding your solution in angular.

Did you try using [ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus).

I guess it would probably look like this:

html:

```
<input ng-focus="YourVariable">
```

And set YourVariable to True.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10080

may be this is helpful to you.

This link said may be it is event/gestured problem.

Comment: or you can try :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859266/input-autofocus-attribute?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

No need to find the element.You can add a directive instead.

```
yourApp.directive('autofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $element[0].focus();
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

and use like :-

```
<input autofocus type="text"/>
```

[Here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mdrqgovs/)