# How to trigger a directive when updating a model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I found a good solution for inline editing content in angular js that is created by running ng-repeat on a model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739227/2228613

To expand on that solution I added a button to the page that has a ng-click directive as so:

```
<button ng-click="addCategory()" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">
<i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> Add Category
</button>
```

The addCategory function is defined in my controller:

```
$scope.addCategory = function(){
    var newCategory = {id:0, name:"Category Name"};
    $scope.categories.unshift(newCategory);
}
```

The goal here is to allow the user to add a new record and automatically trigger the inline-edit directive once the view is updated with the new row. How can I trigger the inline-edit directive in such a manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Directive refresh on parameter change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856824/angular-directive-refresh-on-parameter-change)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One technique that i've used is to have a boolean change values and have a `$watch` on it inside the directive that needs to be triggered.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('someValue', function (val) {
                if (val)
                    // allow edit
                else
                    // hide edit
            });
     }
});
```

Then in your controller you'd set `$scope.someValue = true;` in your ng-click for the button.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aK0HDY?p=preview

---

### UPDATE

I've gone a bit further with the above answer. I've made something more along the lines with what you're after.

**Here's the plunk for it: http://plnkr.co/edit/y7iZpb?p=preview**

This is the new directive:

```
  .directive('editCar', function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          var template = '<span class="car-edit">'+
          '<input type="text" ng-model="car.name" />' +
          '<button ng-click="someValue = false" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></span>';
          scope.$watch('someValue', function (val) {
              if (val) {
                  $(element).html(template).show();
                  $compile($('.car-edit'))(scope);
              }
              else
                  $(element).hide();
          });
        }
      }
  })
```

It replaces the `<edit-car></edit-car>` element with the above template. The save button adds the values to an array called `editedCars`. I've left in some dummy code for submitting the entire thing using `$http.post()`

Comment: How does the directive know which record in the model to invoke the inline-edit functionality for?

Comment: actually now that I think about it, can I just scope.$watch('todos', function(val){...}) to keep track of any changes to the array containing todo objects?

Comment: yes you can do that. I've updated my post with another plunker. This one is more to the point of what you're after.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, what does the `restrict: 'E'` mean?

Comment: restrict 'E' means that the directive will only affect an ELEMENT. in my example, it's <edit-car></edit-car>. Default is 'A' which is ATTRIBUTE, e.g. <div edit-car></div>. There's also 'C' which is CLASS, e.g. <div class="edit-car"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I have one possible solution for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/uzuKki (I worked on the original plunk as you mentioned.)

My idea is

1. Add "editMode" property to TODO model
2. Instead of passing in just `todo.title` to directive's scope, passing in the whole TODO object, which is `inline-edit="todo"` in index.html
3. In inline-edit.html, change every `editMode` to `model.editMode` (and every `model` to `model.title` to display title correctly)
4. In your controller's `add` method, create new object with `editMode = true`, e.g.

   ```
   var newTodo = {id:0, name:"TODO Name", editMode: true};
   $scope.todos.unshift(newTodo);
   ```