# Angular Directive refresh on parameter change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive which is initialized like so:

```
<conversation style="height:300px" type="convo" type-id="{{some_prop}}"></conversation>
```

I'd like it to be smart enough to refresh the directive when `$scope.some_prop` changes, as that implies it should show completely different content.

I have tested it as it is and nothing happens, the linking function doesn't even get called when `$scope.some_prop` changes. Is there a way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Link function only gets called once, so it would not directly do what you are expecting. You need to use angular `$watch` to watch a model variable.

This watch needs to be setup in the link function.

If you use isolated scope for directive then the scope would be

`scope :{typeId:'@' }`

In your link function then you add a watch like

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch("typeId",function(newValue,oldValue) {
        //This gets called when data changes.
    });
 }
```

If you are not using isolated scope use watch on `some_prop`

Comment: Im working on a similar problem as the OP. The AngularJS docs imply that using `=` in `scope:` creates a two-way binding, i.e. changes in child scope propagate up to parent scope and vice versa - is this not the case? I need to be able to tell a directive to update itself from the parent controller.

Comment: @Eno Did you figure this out? Really confusing me!

Comment: @JMK I found these articles useful reading:

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Is it harmful to have the scope of 10000+ directives launching a scope.$watch to listen for a bool to refresh?

Comment: I found that if the parameter is using '=', the solution above doesn't work, and I'm investigating on it..

Answer (score 38):

What you're trying to do is to monitor the property of attribute in directive. You can watch the property of attribute changes using **$observe()** as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('conversation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    compile: function(tElement, attr) {
      attr.$observe('typeId', function(data) {
            console.log("Updated data ", data);
      }, true);

    }
  };
});
```

Keep in mind that I used the 'compile' function in the directive here because you haven't mentioned if you have any models and whether this is performance sensitive.

If you have models, you need to change the '*compile*' function to '*link*' or use '*controller*' and to monitor the property of a model changes, you should use **$watch()**, and take of the angular {{}} brackets from the property, example:

```
<conversation style="height:300px" type="convo" type-id="some_prop"></conversation>
```

And in the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('conversation', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      typeId: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {

      scope.$watch('typeId', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            // You actions here
            console.log("I got the new value! ", newValue);
          }
      }, true);

    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help reloading/refreshing directive on value from parent scope

```
<html>

        <head>
            <!-- version 1.4.5 -->
            <script src="angular.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">

            <my-test reload-on="update"></my-test><br>
            <button ng-click="update = update+1;">update {{update}}</button>
        </body>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', [])
            app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

                $scope.update = 0;
            });
            app.directive('myTest', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'AE',
                    scope: {
                        reloadOn: '='
                    },
                    controller: function($scope) {
                        $scope.$watch('reloadOn', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                            //  all directive code here
                            console.log("Reloaded successfully......" + $scope.reloadOn);
                        });
                    },
                    template: '<span>  {{reloadOn}} </span>'
                }
            });
        </script>


   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app').directive('conversation', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function ($scope, $elm, $attr) {
            $scope.$watch("some_prop", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                  var typeId = $attr.type-id;
                  // Your logic.
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You're under AngularJS 1.5.3 or newer, You should consider to move to components instead of directives.
Those works very similar to directives but with some very useful additional feautures, such as $onChanges(changesObj), one of the lifecycle hook, that will be called whenever one-way bindings are updated.

```
app.component('conversation ', {
    bindings: {
    type: '@',
    typeId: '='
    },
    controller: function() {
        this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
            // check if your specific property has changed
            // that because $onChanges is fired whenever each property is changed from you parent ctrl
            if(!!changes.typeId){
                refreshYourComponent();
            }
        };
    },
    templateUrl: 'conversation .html'
});
```

Here's the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for deepen into components.