# How to watch for a property change in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular directive (with isolate scope) set up like this

```
<div ng="$last" somedirective datajson=mydata myprop="{{ mydata.myspecialprop }}"></div>
```

(which actually gets rendered multiple times because it's inside an ng-repeat.)

Following the instructions of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856824/angular-directive-refresh-on-parameter-change), I tried to observe `myprop` for changes in the directive, however, the code inside the $scope.watch never runs even when the property changes (on a click event). I also tried `scope.$watch(attrs.myprop, function(a,b){...)`and it never ran either. How do I watch for the change in `myprop`

```
myapp.directive('somedirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      datajson: '=',
      myprop: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(scope.myprop, function (a, b) {
        if (a != b) {
          console.log("doesn't get called when a not equal b");
        } else {

        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Update: the click event that changes the property is handle in the controller and I'm guessing this isn't reflected back in the isolate scope directive so that $watch is never getting triggered. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Is `myprop: '@` not having a closing `'` just a copy paste issue?

Comment: Did you try with scope.$watch('myprop' , function(a,b){}});, i have my directive watching a scope variable in that manner and it works correctly.

Comment: @DylannWatt yes just a copy paste/typo

Comment: @Kathir I tried that also, nothing happens when the prop changes

Comment: I think the issue may be that the click event is handle in the controller and the change is not reflects back in Isolate scop directive. Is ypthere a fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an interpolation binding (`@`) you cannot use `scope.$watch`, which is reserved for two-way bindings (`=`) or internal scope properties.

Instead, you need to use `attrs.$observe` which does a similar job:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
   attrs.$observe('myprop', function(newVal, oldVal) {
     // For debug purposes
     console.log('new', newVal, 'old', oldVal);
     if (newVal != oldVal){
          console.log("doesn't get called when newVal not equal oldVal");
      } else {
          // ...
     } 
   });
 }
```

Also, everytime `myprop` change, the `newVal` *will* be different from its `oldVal`, so it is a bit weird that you skip that case which is the only one which will happen.

NOTE: you also forgot doublequotes for the `datajson` two-way binding: `datajson="mydata"`

Answer (score 0):

Intead of passing a string, try it as variable

```
scope: {
     datajson: '=',
     myprop: '=' //change to equal so you can watch it (it has more sense i think)
  }
```

then change html, removing braces from mydata.myspecialprop

```
<div ng="$last" somedirective datajson="mydata" myprop="mydata.myspecialprop"></div>
```