# AngularJS - How to refresh directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I've created a simple datepicker directive which have an "options".

So I start the datepicker with a set of options, and then because of business logic I change those options, but this are not being refreshed.

In this example, I need to update de datepicker start date of the "endDate" to the same date as "startDate".

Here's my code:

Directive:

```
function datepicker() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            options : '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var opts = scope.options || {};

            element.datepicker({
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                forceParse: false,
                autoclose: true,
                useCurrent: true,
                format: opts.format || 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                startDate : opts.startDate || ''
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.evaluation = {};

$scope.startDatepickerOptions = {
    startDate : new Date()
};

$scope.endDatepickerOptions = {
    startDate : new Date()
};

$scope.$watch('evaluation.startDate', function(newValue) {
    $scope.endDatepickerOptions.startDate = newValue;
});
```

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="evaluation.startDate" name="startDate" datepicker options="startDatepickerOptions"/>

<input type="text" ng-model="evaluation.endDate" name="endDate" datepicker options="endDatepickerOptions"/>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856824/angular-directive-refresh-on-parameter-change)?

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the solution:

I needed to add an equality watcher on the directive link function. So far, due to dates/strings issues, I've implemented the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/)

Here's the final code:

**Directive (link function)**:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    var opts = scope.options || {};

    element.datepicker({
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        autoclose: true,
        useCurrent: true,
        format: opts.format || 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate : opts.startDate || ''
    });

    scope.$watch('options.startDate', function(newValue) {
        if(newValue) {
            element.datepicker('setStartDate', newValue);
            element.datepicker('setDate', "");
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.startDatepickerOptions = {
    startDate : moment().toDate()
};

$scope.endDatepickerOptions = {
    startDate : moment().toDate()
};

$scope.$watch('evaluation.startDate', function(newValue) {
    if(newValue)
        $scope.endDatepickerOptions['startDate'] = moment(newValue, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();
});
```