# How to set focus on a textbox after $http success in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find out a way to write a Angular JS directive which will set focus on a textbox after saving data using $http.

I am trying to solve the following problem.

1. User fill up a form
2. On ng-submit I save the data using $http call.
3. I want to put the focus to first element of form after successfull save.

As I understand that DOM manipulation needs to be done via Directive. Can anyone provide a simple directive sample code to do this?

- UPDATE -
  I should put my code with my question. Here it is

[image: Sorry I should put my code before. Here is what I tried but didn't work]

[image: Html Code]

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs

Comment: I didn't put any code for $http call but put some comments to make my intention clear, what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not show any research effort and is therefore likely to stay unanswered or get closed (besides the fact that it is a duplicate). Nevertheless, here some simple example code

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
 return {
   link: function(scope, element) {

        element[0].focus(); 

    }
  });
}
```

Within a directives linking function, you have access to the element. Use this to handle it. See also:

[Angular API: element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)

Comment: I added my research effort. Can you put any light how to make this work?

Comment: element[0] --- I was simply trying on element and was getting a undefined function exception... Not realizing element is an array .
  Which i cannot comprehend why..!! The directive is an attribute.. can be applied to one element only.. !!