# Not sure how to hide a div when clicking OUTSIDE of the div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is a follow-up question to this question: [AngularJS input with focus kills ng-repeat filter of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678813/angularjs-input-with-focus-kills-ng-repeat-filter-of-list)

Basically my code is using AngularJS to pop-out a div (a drawer) on the right for filtering a list of things.  Most times this is used the UI is blocked so clicking on that blocking div closes the drawer.  But in some cases we don't block the UI and need to allow the user to click outside of the drawer to cancel the search or select something else on the page.

My initial thought was to attach a window.onclick handler when the drawer opens and if anything is clicked other than the drawer it should close the drawer.  That's how I would do it in a pure JavaScript app.  But in Angular it is being a bit more difficult.

Here is a jsfiddle with a sample that I based on @Yoshi's jsBin example: http://jsfiddle.net/tpeiffer/kDmn8/

The relevant piece of code from this sample is below.  Basically if the user clicks outside of the drawer I invoke $scope.toggleSearch so that $scope.open is set back to false.

The code works, and even though the $scope.open goes from true to false it doesn't modify the DOM.  I'm sure this has something to do with the lifecycle of events or perhaps when I modify $scope (since it is from a separate event) that it is a copy and not the original...

The ultimate goal on this will be for it to be a directive for ultimate reusability.  If anyone can point me in the right direction to do that I would be grateful.

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function () {

    $scope.open = !$scope.open;

    if ($scope.open) {
        $scope.$window.onclick = function (event) {
            closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(event, $scope.toggleSearch);
        };
    } else {
        $scope.$window.onclick = null;
    }
};
```

and

```
function closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(event, callbackOnClose) {

    var clickedElement = event.target;
    if (!clickedElement) return;

    var elementClasses = clickedElement.classList;
    var clickedOnSearchDrawer = elementClasses.contains('handle-right') 
        || elementClasses.contains('drawer-right') 
        || (clickedElement.parentElement !== null 
            && clickedElement.parentElement.classList.contains('drawer-right'));
    if (!clickedOnSearchDrawer) {
        callbackOnClose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The drawer is not closing because the click event occurs outside the digest cycle and  Angular doesn't know that $scope.open has changed. To fix it you can call $scope.$apply() after $scope.open is set to false, this will trigger the digest cycle.

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function () {
    $scope.open = !$scope.open;
    if ($scope.open) {
        $scope.$window.onclick = function (event) {
            closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(event, $scope.toggleSearch);
        };
    } else {
        $scope.open = false;
        $scope.$window.onclick = null;
        $scope.$apply(); //--> trigger digest cycle and make angular aware. 
    }
};
```

Here is your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk6xu/).

I was also trying to create a directive for the search drawer, if it helps (it needs some fixes :)). Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/33/edit).

Comment: Thank you very much @Bertrand! That $apply was exactly what I was missing!  I'm on day 5 of using Angular (professionally) - still some key concepts that it is going to take me a while to get familiar with!  Hopefully I can return the favor in the near future!  I'll check out that JSBin for the directive, and post the results when it is done and working.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest to add $event.stopPropagation(); on the view right after on the ng-click. You don't need to use jQuery.

```
<button ng-click="toggleSearch();$event.stopPropagation();">toggle</button>
```

Then, you can use this simplified js.

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function () {
    $window.onclick = null;
    $scope.menuOpen = !$scope.menuOpen;

    if ($scope.model.menuOpen) {
        $window.onclick = function (event) {
            $scope.menuOpen = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer will throw an error if you click on the button to close the drawer/popup, and the button is located outside of it, because `$apply()` will be executed twice.

This is a simplified version, that doesn't need call the whole `toggleSearch()` function again and prevents the double `$apply()`.

```
$scope.toggleSearch = function() {

  $scope.open = !$scope.open;

  if ($scope.open) {
    $window.onclick = function(event) {
      var clickedElement = event.target;
      if (!clickedElement) return;

      var clickedOnSearchDrawer = elementClasses.contains('handle-right') || elementClasses.contains('drawer-right') || (clickedElement.parentElement !== null && clickedElement.parentElement.classList.contains('drawer-right'));

      if (!clickedOnSearchDrawer) {
        $scope.open = !$scope.open;
        $window.onclick = null;
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    }
  } else {
    $window.onclick = null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a solution i was 100% happy with, this is what i used:

```
<div class="options">
    <span ng-click="toggleAccountMenu($event)">{{ email }}</span>
    <div ng-show="accountMenu" class="accountMenu">
        <a ng-click="go('account')">Account</a>
        <a ng-click="go('logout')">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the span with ng-click is used to open the menu, the div.accountMenu is toggled open or closed

```
$scope.accountMenu = false;
$scope.toggleAccountMenu = function(e){
    if(e) e.stopPropagation();
    $scope.accountMenu = !$scope.accountMenu;
    if ($scope.accountMenu) {
        $window.onclick = function(e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            if(!target) return;
            if(!target.hasClass('accountMenu') && !target.is($('.accountMenu').children())){
                $scope.toggleAccountMenu();
            }               
        };
    } else if (!e) {
        $window.onclick = null;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

This uses jQuery for child checking but you can probably do it without if needed.

I was getting some nasty errors with other peoples version, like trying to call $apply() when its already in a cycle, my version prevents propagation and safe-checks against $apply()