# AngularJS trying to hide popup menu when outside area is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have my HTML set up in the following way:

```
<div>
    <a href="" ng-click="$scope.show_menu = !$scope.show_menu">Options</a>

    <div class="options_box" ng-show="$scope.show_menu">
        <button>Option1</button>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my AngularJS code:

```
myApp.controller('myController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $scope.show_menu = false;
    $scope.$window.onclick = function(){
        $scope.show_menu = false;
        $scope.apply();
    };

    ...

} ]);
```

When the page loads, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
```

If I remove my `$window.onclick` bit of code, the error disappears and clicking the `Options` button successfully opens/closes the options popup. What is the correct way to ensure the menu is hidden when any area outside the popup menu is clicked?

Comment: Try injecting $window to the controller and simply use $window.onclick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$window` isn't a property on the scope.  [AngularJS $window documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) says `$window` is a global object. Vaidik is correct in the method to get `$window` into your controller, so having done that you can write `$window.onclick...` not `$scope.$window`.

I'm not sure this is the answer you need though. I would question if it would work if you clicked on a button outside of the menu, as the button would handle the click preventing to event from bubbling up (propagating) to the window...

If you have to click to hide the menu then perhaps you could click on the same button that opened it by toggling `ng-show`?

Alternatively the menu could just hide when it looses focus i.e. the mouse moves outside the area of the menu - by adding an `ng-blur` directive to your menu element.

See [ngBlur documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur).

Comment: Injecting `$window` into the controller and using it without `$scope` prepended to it resolved my original error. But now I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function` error when clicking on the window.

Comment: This seems to be a related question with an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706847/angularjs-not-sure-how-to-hide-a-div-when-clicking-outside-of-the-div I think it may give you a clue as to a solution to your new error but it also hints at the next problem you might hit which is you change happens outside the digest cycle and means things don't get hidden when you think. Your click link open/close works I'd be tempted to give ng-blur a go for closing when the mouse is outside the menu. But I note the angularjs site doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks, the related SO question helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$window` like so:

```
myApp.controller('myController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$window', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $window) {

    $scope.show_menu = false;
    $scope.$window.onclick = function(){
        $scope.show_menu = false;
        $scope.apply();
    };

    ...

} ]);
```