# Hide on OutSide Click in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've a code like this...
I'm using 'left-menu-active' class to show and hide menu in css...

i've 2 issues and both of them i want to solve using angular js...

1. I wants to add class on parent using angular js..
2. I wants to hide left menu when we click outside of menu (using
   angular js)

   ```
   <div class="left-menu">
       <span class="icon icon-menu"></span>
       <div class="left-menu-holder">
           //Content goes here...
       </div>
   </div>

   .left-menu {
       transition: left 0.25s linear;
       position: absolute;
       width: 200px;
       left: -200px;
    }
    .left-menu-active {
       left: 0;
    }
   ```

Somebody plz help me to solve this problem..

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706847/not-sure-how-to-hide-a-div-when-clicking-outside-of-the-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope it help you 
//HTML

```
<div class="left-menu" data-ng-class="menuOpened ? 'left-menu-active' : ''" >
    <span class="icon icon-menu"></span>
    <div class="left-menu-holder">
        //Content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
<button type="" data-ng-click="openMenu($event)">Open Menu</button>
```

//JS

```
function appController($scope,$document) {
    $scope.menuOpened = false;
    $document.on('click', handler);

    function handler() {
       $scope.menuOpened = false;
    }
    $scope.openMenu = function(event) {
       $scope.menuOpened = !$scope.menuOpened;
       event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will close the menu even when an item on the menu is clicked.