# Focus function is not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple focus is not working in angular

```
<div class="search pull-right tab-{{ showDetails2 }}" data-ng-click="showDetails2 = !showDetails2; showDetails = false; showDetails1 = false;searchFocus();">
```

html

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="model.fedSearchTerm"
                    placeholder="New Search" required class="span12 fedsearch-box" />
```

MY function

```
$scope.searchFocus = function() {
            $('.fedsearch-box').focus();
        };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs look at Mark's answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a more robust implementation that works very well :

```
myApp.directive('focusMe', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function(value) {
                if(value === true) {
                    element[0].focus();
                    element[0].select();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});


<input type="text" ng-model="stuff.name" focus-me="true" />
```

Comment: This does work very well. Could you explain why the $watch is required to wrap the  focus and select? I tried removing $watch and of course it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same issue. Solved it by enclosing the focus command inside $timeout. Make sure you pass the $timeout parameter in the .controller function.

```
$timeout(function() { $('.fedsearch-box').focus(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a directive for this purpose like;

```
myApp.directive('focus', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
           element.focus();
  }
});
```

And in your HTML;

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="model.fedSearchTerm"
                    placeholder="New Search" required focus />
```