# Angular button click prevented when focusing out invalid input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have prepared the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XVCtNX29hFfXtvREYtVF?p=preview where I ask you to:

1: digit something in the input field

2: directly click on the button (without touching anything else).

```
element.on('click',function(){
    scope.clicked=true;
    scope.$apply();
})
```

Question: why the onclick function doesn't get called? (I know I have used element.on('click',...), I can't use ng-click here, don't ask why.

Do you have any idea on why this happens?

Comment: it has to do with your ng-model-options on the input field. if you change the click event to be a mousedown event, it'll work. take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137592/2460773

Comment: will it work the same also on mobile?

Comment: Nope, this actually doesn't help me because I need that blur event to be fired

Comment: I see it's working, correct me if Im wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/ezzxYkuV8jgMkxscPqU6?p=preview

Comment: Nope, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you add 'default' in  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur'}" ng-model="var" of your input tag

for more information [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)