# In angularjs, how to set focus on input on form submit if input has error?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code and I want to set focus on first name textbox on form submit if first name textbox has error like `$error.required`,`$error.pattern`,`$error.minlength` or `$error.maxlength`.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="clientForm" id="clientForm" novalidate ng-submit="clientForm.$valid" ng-class="{ loading:form.submitting }">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" ng-model="client.firstName" class="form-control" required autofocus name="firstName" autocomplete="off" ng-maxlength="100" ng-minlength=3 ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" />
        <!--<span ng-show="clientForm.firstName.$dirty && clientForm.firstName.$invalid" class="error">First Name is required.</span>-->
        <div class="errors" ng-show="clientForm.$submitted || clientForm.firstName.$touched">
            <div class="error" ng-show="clientForm.firstName.$error.required">
                First Name is required.
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="clientForm.firstName.$error.pattern">
                Enter valid name.
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="clientForm.firstName.$error.minlength">
                First Name is required to be at least 3 characters
            </div>
            <div class="error" ng-show="clientForm.firstName.$error.maxlength">
                First Name cannot be longer than 100 characters
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of:
[Set focus on first invalid input in AngularJs form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365121/set-focus-on-first-invalid-input-in-angularjs-form)

You can use a directive on the form:

```
<form accessible-form>
    ...    
</form>

app.directive('accessibleForm', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem) {

            // set up event handler on the form element
            elem.on('submit', function () {

                // find the first invalid element
                var firstInvalid = elem[0].querySelector('.ng-invalid');

                // if we find one, set focus
                if (firstInvalid) {
                    firstInvalid.focus();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is a working Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wBFY9ZZRzLuDUi2SyErC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:  i.e add `ng-focus="clientForm.$error"` in first name input

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="clientForm.$invalid" ng-model="client.firstName" class="form-control" required autofocus name="firstName" autocomplete="off" ng-maxlength="100" ng-minlength=3 ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to handle this using directive. For example:

It will iterate through the element(s) and check if the `focusNow` attribute is true or not. Make sure that the error handler code sets the expression true/false.

```
.directive('focusNow', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focusNow, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                        var ele = angular.element(element[i].parentNode);
                        if (!ele.hasClass('ng-hide')) { //Skip those elements which are hidden.
                            element[i].focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and in the HTML, you'll have:

```
<input type="text" focus-now="expression" />
```

where `expression` will be a normal expression which will evaluate to true in case of error.