# Subscribing to an Observable based on conditions

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

**Background**

Im using Reactive Forms that expands over two tabs (first half of the page alone has tabs) and then a long page with Submit button at the bottom. I do the validation on click of the Submit button.

On clicking of Submit button,  the page needs to scroll to the error form field when Validation fails.

I'm also able to load the tab based on errors in FormGroups.

**Problem**

1. The scroll happens before the tab loads.
2. To solve Point 1, I subscribed to the animationDone event and then scrolled to the point inside of it.

```
submit(){
   //code to select the desired tab
   this.selectedTab.animationDone.subscribe(res => {
   this.myElement.nativeElement.ownerDocument.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid mat-form-field')[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
          });
}
```

All works fine until this point !!!

3. Once the Approve Button is clicked, the subscription subscribes, and the page scrolls to the errors whenever a new Tab is selected. I wanted to unsubscribe to this observable and later subscribe back whenever the Submit button is clicked again.
4. I tried unsubscribe, but I'm not able to subscribe to it again. This sometimes destroys the subscribe function and throws error

I think I'm missing something and reaching out for help. Thanks in advance !!

**More Code as Requested**

```
submit()
{
    if(this.bookingForm.valid){
    // do some actions ....
     }
    else {
    this.bookingForm.markAllAsTouched();
    //subscribing to the event before selecting the tab

    this.selectedTab.animationDone.subscribe(res => {

     this.myElement.nativeElement.ownerDocument.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid mat-form-field')[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

          });

    // code to select the Tab where the error occurs .....
     this.selectedTab.selectedIndex = this.errorIndex;

    //unsubscribe
    this.selectedTab.animationDone.unsubscribe()

    } // close of else block
}// close of submit Function
```

The unsubscribe (or similar function) is required as this should subscribe only when the Submit button is clicked. If it is not unsubscribed (or paused) then the subscribe function is being called everytime the tab is changed and the page keeps scrolling up and down based on errors.

**Page View**

This is just for demonstration.
[image: Page view]

> EDIT 2 below

Here is the [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3qfaq). This is just a sample page, My page has much more fields and form Groups compared to this.

**Recreating the Issue**

*Scenario 1*

1. Fill in the fields - Name , Tab1 , Details1
2. Keep tab1 selected and click on Submit.
3. This should scroll up and show **Tab2**. Works as expected! The delay is agreeable.
4. Now manually switch to Tab1.
5. You can see the page scrolling to the Details 2 field.
6. **This scroll happens whenever the tab is switched.** How do i stop this?
7. Im able to achieve this by uncommenting line 38 in app.component.ts file. - The unsubscribe command.

   - In this, there is an error when i click on the Submit button more than once.
   - When i click for the second time, the subscribe dosen't work.

Comment: Can you paste more of your code here. I am not sure if this is the right way to achieve what you are trying to do.
But you can use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Observable` and do `next` after certain amount of time.

Comment: @SuyashGupta, I have updated my question with more details

Comment: Can you share your html too? And what do you mean by `The scroll happens before the tab loads` ?

Comment: What all events are attached to Approve Button? Where is it located on the page?

Comment: I will recreate my issue in stackBlitz and will share the link here.

Comment: @SuyashGupta and Kriti, I have edited the question with the StackBlitz link and the steps to recreate the issue

Comment: @SuyashGupta, were you able to access my StackBlitz link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. I was a little busy.

I didn't look into the `animation` part that you were trying, instead I focused on the basics as we just needed to focus on the element if it is `invalid`.

**[Method 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nupq1m)**

```
submit() {
  if(this.testForm.valid) {
    //Code to Submit
  } else {
    ((document.getElementsByClassName('mat-input-element ng-invalid')[0]) as HTMLElement).focus();
  }
}
```

**[Method 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugrjy7)**

[I came across this very cool way to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084182/8908267)

```
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material';
import { QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChildren(MatInput) inputs: QueryList <MatInput>;

submit() {
  if(this.testForm.valid) {
    //Code to Submit
  } else {
    this.inputs.find(input => !input.ngControl.valid).focus();
  }
}
```

---

Also, if you always want `Tab 1` to be selected first if it is `invalid`, then put the other condition in `else/ else if` section -

```
if(this.testForm.get('tab1').errors) {
  this.tabControl.selectedIndex = 0;
} else if(this.testForm.get('tab2').errors) {
  this.tabControl.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

---

One more thing, you'll have to put a slight delay before focusing on `invalid` elements as creating `input` element for `Tab 2` in DOM takes nanoSeconds of time and it focuses on `Details 1` if either of the `Tab 1` or `2` is `invalid`.

```
delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
  }
```

Just call this before `focus()` and after `switching tabs check`

```
await this.delay(1);
```

If you don't want to set `delay`, just set `focus()` on `animationDone` event again and set the `animationDuration` time to minimum so you wouldn't see `focus` on `Details 1` in real time.

Follow the `Methods` links for complete flow and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have small glitch in this method of using delay. How fool proof is this? And what if the tab takes more time to load? In my scenario the tab itself is a seperate complex component and it is lazy loaded. Just to ensure this I had to subscribe to the animation done observer.

Comment: To identify whether the tab has loaded or not, following  are the possibilities : 1. Animation done; 2. SelectedTabChange; Both are observables.

Comment: And thank you for your suggestion of focusing on the input field rather than just scrolling. I will certainly use that.

Comment: I'm sorry. Focus on `Details 1` was not getting set due to time taken to switch tabs, instead it was due to creation of the `input` element of other `Tab` in DOM. So, we needed to re-initialize the `ng-invalid` element array.
I have updated the solution in stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nupq1m) incase you don't want to go with `delay` thing.

Comment: And you can verify the same here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugrjy7 as I have set the `animationDuration` to `800 ms` but delay is only `1 ms` but still `focus()` is working fine so there is no harm in going with the `delay` solution.

Comment: Also, you can switch tabs using two-way binding event that is provided by `Angular Material Tabs` - `[(selectedIndex)]`. No need to do it using `ViewChildren`.

Comment: Last thing - `this.testForm.markAllAsTouched()` is not needed until you use `<form>` tags instead of `div` and put the `submit button` inside the form.

Comment: Thanks Suyash. I will use the delay method and the focus(instead of scrollIntoView).  But im still not convinced using the delay; yet I will use, as i have no better solution.