# Perform focus after underlying data changes

Tags: angularjs

```
reportingApp.controller('tradeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.trades = [
        //{ticker: 'AAPL', shares: 100, limit: 500},
        //{ticker: 'GE', shares: -400, limit: 600},
    ];          
    $scope.addNewTrade = function () {
        console.log ('addNewTade executes');
            $scope.trades.push({ticker: "", shares: "", limit: ""});
           $("table tr:last td:first").focus();
    }
```

The focus() function does not work, because at the time it gets to run, the html row has not changed yet. Where should I put my focus code?

Comment: You shouldn't do DOM manipulation in a controller. You could make a directive, watch for changes to the scope and you could try doing a $timeout(function(){ element.focus();});

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs

Comment: @TestersGonnaTest I am very new to AngularJs. Directive is kinda difficult for me to understand to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my custom directive:

```
app.directive('customAutofocus', function() {
  return{
         restrict: 'A',

         link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           scope.$watch(function(){
             return scope.$eval(attrs.customAutofocus);
             },function (newValue){
               if (newValue == true){
                   element[0].focus();
               }
           });
         }
     };
})
```

Use it:

```
custom-autofocus="$index == trades.length-1"
```

Set the element focused when it's the last one.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tboROHFQ8nrifcP9IHvj?p=preview)