# AngularJS - ngFocus and ngBlur Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried adding a code for ngFocus and ngBlur but everytime i start it, it wont seem to function, heres my js code:

```
function focusCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.hasFocus = false;
}
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('ngFocus', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return function (scope, element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr['ngFocus']);
            element.on('focus', function (event) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    fn(scope, {$event: event});
                });
            });
        };
    }])
    .directive('ngBlur', ['$parse', function($parse) {
        return function(scope, element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr['ngBlur']);
            element.on('blur', function(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    fn(scope, {$event:event});
                });
            });
        };
    }]);
```

I'll add my html as well:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input ng-blur="hasFocus=false" ng-focus="hasFocus=true" type="text"  required="required" class="form-control form-validation" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="artist.name" />
</div>
```

It gives me this error every time i reload the page, and i can't seem to understand the problem!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'module' Focus.js:4
(anonymous function)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those directive come with angular (not sure which version they were introduced in

[ngFocus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)

[ngBlur](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

That being said, when you are creating directives, do not prefix them with ng. That prefix is reserved by angular.

`"do not prefix your own directives with ng or they might conflict with directives included in a future version of Angular"` [reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#!)

If you want the functionality of setting focus to a control via a field on your controller's scope take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs/14837021#14837021).

Answer (score 1):

The Brocco answer is ok,
if you want to make custom directive of focus or blur, you can look at [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kwfNGUKx3K1mc7ConNcf?p=preview)