# Strange cursor placement in modal when using autofocus in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with the cursor placement when using autofocus in IE. The image should display the issue clearly.

[image: fubar cursor placement]

Luckily I've been able to reproduce this in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SSJCfl0P9PuivL34XJZ1?p=preview). I've stripped it down to the bare essentials, so it should be easy enough to see what's going on.

How do I make IE behave?

**AngularJS** (Also available in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SSJCfl0P9PuivL34XJZ1?p=preview))

```
app.directive('autofocus', [
  '$timeout', function($timeout) {
      return function(scope, elem, attr) {
          scope.$on('autofocus', function(e) {
              $timeout(function() {
                  elem[0].focus();
              });
          });
      };
  }
]);

/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs */
app.factory('autofocus', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return function() {
      $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('autofocus');
      });
  };
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        url: '/main'
    });
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main.modal', {
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$state', '$stateParams', '$modal', 'autofocus',
            function ($state, $stateParams, $modal, autofocus) {
                var instance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'modal.html'
                });
                instance.result.then(function () {
                    // OK
                    // GOTO parent state
                    $state.go('^');
                }, function () {
                    // Cancel
                    // GOTO parent state
                    $state.go('^');
                });
                instance.opened.then(function() {
                  autofocus();
                });
            }
        ]
    });
}]);
```

**Markup**

```
<form>
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" name="foo" autofocus>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like i might be the "slide"-animation which is to blame.
i managed to fix this by forcing the modal to fade in without sliding, by adding "windowClass: modal fade in" like so:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main.modal', {
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$state', '$stateParams', '$modal', 'autofocus',
            function ($state, $stateParams, $modal, autofocus) {
                var instance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                    windowClass: 'modal fade in'
                });
                instance.result.then(function () {
                    // OK
                    // GOTO parent state
                    $state.go('^');
                }, function () {
                    // Cancel
                    // GOTO parent state
                    $state.go('^');
                });
                instance.opened.then(function() {
                  autofocus();
                });
            }
        ]
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 11):

Thank you for documenting this issue and for the diagnose. This was the only topic I could find about this and it seems like a frequent problem. Isn't this script sollution bit of an overkill?

css sollution for the problem::

```
.modal.fade {
transition:opacity .3s linear;
}
```

It kills the slide in effect but leaves the fade in.

Comment: Not sure why would someone put a -1 on this, because it actually worked for me. Actually better than providing a custom class to every modal I have to open in each controller

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and resolve my problem:

```
<form>
 <div class="table-condensed">
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    ....
   <tr>
    <td>
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```