# Insert sibling item to Angular-UI-tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, angular-ui-tree

I need to insert a sibling item to tree on click in angular-ui-tree (https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree)

it means I have:

```
<item><input value"item A #1"><button>insert under</button></item>
<item><input value"item B #2"><button>insert under</button></item>
<item><input value"item C #3"><button>insert under</button></item>
<item><input value"item D #4"><button>insert under</button></item>
```

when I click in Item C "insert under" I need to add new item between Item B and Item C - and focus this new item's input.

How to do that?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made it more complicated for yourself by not providing exact sample of your data and html, so I made only generic solution but should help you.

1) how to make "add below" button

ui-tree only does render your tree model. So as is natural in angular, only thing you need to do is to alter the data in the way you want - add node under some other.

So you only need to get array of sibling nodes and current index. Index is available in `$index` since ui-tree uses standart `ngRepeat`. More tricky is to get the array of siblings. Quick look at documentation reveal `$parentNodesScope` is scope of tree-nodes (ie siblings container) and this scope then contains `$modelValue` which is, guess, siblings array. So this does the job:

```
<button ng-click='$parentNodesScope.$modelValue.splice($index+1,0,{value:"New",nodes:[]})'>Add below</button>
```

Note that `{value:"New",nodes:[]}` is what will be added, change it to what data structure you have.

2) how to make input of added node focused

There is lot of info on how to focus inputs in agular, for example here
[How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

I like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20865048 answer most and it works. It basically focus all elements when they are insterted to DOM - so also when ui-tree re-render the tree with new nodes. Drawback is that after first page load, the last node will be focused, but it's now up to you to deal with it.

You can find whole demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWGvJY4YHaDlCG26W7Fd?p=preview

Comment: I need to use this Angular-UI-Tree with newer version - 2.2.0, but there is a problem with siblings - what is passwed to the nodes variable.

I put it to demo http://plnkr.co/edit/QUZ72R?p=preview where is vissible the error. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Inspecting the source code (which is btw nice) revealed the magic: ```$parentNodesScope.$modelValue``` which is actually documented but not directly :D - ```$parentNodesScope``` points to scope of parent tree-nodes and its ```$modelValue``` points to the list of nodes of that subtree. So no need for ```ng-init``` anymore. Check http://plnkr.co/edit/MHA37p?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First I've added onclick event listeners to the HTML buttons:

```
<item><input value="item A #1"><button onclick="onClickItem(this);">insert under</button></item>
<item><input value="item B #2"><button onclick="onClickItem(this);">insert under</button></item>
<item><input value="item C #3"><button onclick="onClickItem(this);">insert under</button></item>
<item><input value="item D #4"><button onclick="onClickItem(this);">insert under</button></item>
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
<script>
function onClickItem( clickedItem)
{
    var newElement = document.createElement( "item");
    newElement.innerHTML = '<input><button>insert under</button>';

    if( newElement.addEventListener)
        newElement.lastChild.addEventListener( "click", function() { onClickItem( newElement) });
    else if( newElement.attachEvent)
        newElement.lastChild.attachEvent( "onclick", function() { onClickItem( newElement) });  // for IE8 or earlier

    var parentNode = clickedItem.parentNode.parentNode;
    newElement = parentNode.insertBefore( newElement, clickedItem.parentNode.nextElementSibling );
}
</script>
```

The first two lines of the JavaScript just create the new item (I assumed you would want the same elements in the new items as in the original ones, but you can change that if you want something else).

Then it adds the same event listener as the original buttons have - that means the new item behaves the same as the originals, so that clicking on a new one creates yet another item.

Finally it uses the JavaScript insertBefore DOM method to insert the new item into the tree, referencing nextElementSibling to make sure it's inserted after the clicked item, not before. I hope this gives you what you want.

Comment: I need it in AngualrJS, Lukas's version works really great, but thanks for your help!