# Set focus on the first input field on dropdown toggle through angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<th class="dropdown" id="header">
  <span>Label</span>
    <span id="filter" class="sort_row glyphicon glyphicon-filter   dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ></span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-dropdown" role="menu">
     <li >
  <span class="input-group value">
<input type="text"  id="inputField1" name="inputField1"  class="form-  control" ng-model='inputFieldFirst'/>
        </span>
       </li>
      </ul>
   </span>
 </th>
```

Here I want to focus on the input field when the filter is clicked and the dropdown opens.
Is there a way in which I dont have to use the id of the input field and set focus on the input that is present in the dropdown

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14833326/1449624) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably try this.

```
$( "#filter" ).click(function() {
  $( ".dropdown-menu input:first-child()" ).focus();
});
```