# Scope value reset on element focus of form in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple Form validation, when Form is submitted

$scope.error shows error if there is any exist

```
<div class="card" ng-show="error">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap assertive">
    {{error}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there way to reset $scope.error if any element in form gets focused?

Comment: `ngFocus` is in there for an event based function.. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

Comment: so to check any element, i should have ng-focus on all elements?

Comment: you could define a directive to monitor all input types.. but it would be a bit of work! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field

Comment: so then directive will be injected in all input types, if I understand it right?! ok, directive or ng-focus might actually help, but in case of directive, Can I change scope variable from directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-focus in each fields

```
<input type="text"  ng-focus="error=false" />
<div class="card" ng-show="error">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap assertive">
    {{error}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I also use it as error equals empty ng-focus="error=''"?

Comment: Thank you Vaibahv Shah! That I think works in my case!