# How to focus on element inside Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jqlite

I have the following code below, which is supposed to open a modal with an input box as soon as you start typing. I have made progress to the point where the modal opens, however I can't figure out how to focus on the actual input box (inside my link function in the directive). Any ideas would be appreciated. Also, if there are any other suggestions for improvements, please let me know.

Please see this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMN56G

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

  //CAN'T FIGURE THIS OUT
  var input = elem.children()[1]
  input.focus();
  console.log(input)      
}
```

And HTML....

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <input type="text" ng-model="selected.query"/>
      Selected: <b>{{ query}}</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Does 'input' actually have a value or is it undefined?

Comment: if you look at the HTML, you will see an input field. essentially it's the input box that i'm trying to focus on

Comment: Yes, I believe that the input is there if you look at the html...but does the selector give you a reference to it at that point in your code?

Comment: Yes it does, if you see the console log statement, it returns the modal-body div...and inside of that is the input box. So, essentially, I can get the modal-body div, but I can't figure out how to get to the input inside of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6kHuj0?p=preview

Comment: What do you get when logging the var input? Also...adding a timeout like @vp_arth suggest will indeed probably fix your problem but I was trying to get to the essence here ;)

Comment: Your selecting the modal body div not the input.

Comment: `$timeout` need for render modal. Other approach is delegate this work to input directive. There are ton of variants in the linked question.

Comment: but i don't want to use another directive... i want to do all of the work in the same directive