# ngFocus not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

Following is my code snippet in which I need to focus an input field on the basis of checkbox value, If I check the checkbox it should focus the second element which somehow not working. Let me know what i am doing wrong here with Angular.

Note - I already checked few examples using directives, but I want to know what I am missing here concept/code etc

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.check" />
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input2" ng-focus="vm.check" />
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input3" />
```

Plnkr Code - http://plnkr.co/edit/q15Jht9AsVj60xrutVfm?p=preview

Comment: normally the expression of `ng-focus` is a event handler which will handle whatever you want to do on focusing the element, is that what you want to do? you may find more from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-focus` is used to

> Specify custom behavior on focus event

not to set focus.

check [angular-docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)

To meet your case refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Answer (score 8):

`ngFocus` doesn't work the way you think. The expression under `ngFocus` is triggered on input focus, that's all.

If you want to focus it depending on the state of a var, you should use a directive. Example :

```
myApp.directive('syncFocusWith', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      focusValue: "=syncFocusWith"
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
      $scope.$watch("focusValue", function(currentValue, previousValue) {
        if (currentValue === true && !previousValue) {
          $element[0].focus();
        } else if (currentValue === false && previousValue) {
          $element[0].blur();
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

And update your html to use this directive :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input2" sync-focus-with="vm.check"/>
```

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dAgtRM6xOiJyhNBF5HSM?p=preview)

*Credits to [Alex from Emberex.com](https://www.emberex.com/programmatically-setting-focus-angularjs-way/) for sharing this snippet.*