# Link focus on table click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table where the first cell on every row contains a link. When the user mouseclicks on a row I want **the link on the same row** to get focus().

I want to do this with an Angular directive. I'm using Angular but I think the solution comes down to jQuery usage.

This is a simplified version of what I've got now:

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <table border="1" focus-on-link-please>
      <tr>
        <td><a href>Link A</a></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href>Link B</a></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.directive('focusOnLinkPlease', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    elem.bind('click', function(event) {
      console.log('click!')
      event.target.closest('tr').find('a').focus(); // Does not work :(
    });

  }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/azoxwym6/)

Any tips?

Comment: is this a wrong fiddle?

Comment: `event.target.closest('tr').querySelector('a').focus();`  @aw04 It wasn't, now fixed   https://jsfiddle.net/azoxwym6/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff , try the fiddle again. Should be ok

Comment: Nice, @A.Wolff. If you post an answer i will accept it as the solution.

Comment: @HoffZ But i'm not an angular dev and i guess there is better to do, just not sure... :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modifed my jQuery to make it work.

```
elem.bind('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click!')
  var tr = $(event.target).closest('tr') || $(event.target);
  if (tr) {
    tr.find('a').focus();
  }      
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/c4emc54w/) with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write directive to take focus.
like here [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)
Use binding to connect things:

```
   <table>
      <tr ng-click="focusA = true">
        <td><a href focus-me="focusA">Link A</a></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-click="focusB = true">
        <td><a href focus-me="focusB">Link B</a></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```