# How can I set .focus() on a custom directive in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Fairly new to javascript. I was wondering with the following tag, besides having to manually put in Ids, is there a way to set .focus() to the container (custom directive)? The custom directive is a container div that acts as a tile.

```
<tile class="ng-scope gridster-item" tilevalue="1" gridster-item="tile" row="0" col = "0" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"> </tile>
```

Comment: can you post some code on what youve tried?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a focus attribute directive. e.g.

```
<tile class="ng-scope gridster-item" focus-directive tilevalue="1" gridster-item="tile" row="0" col = "0" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"></tile>
```

[Here's a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)