# Kendo grid with angularjs for data entry app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, data-entry

```js
  //-> Grid Sample data for demo purposes

           
           
            var s1 = [];

            var d2 = [];
        

            //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

            //-> Grid Start


            var configAddPaymentsEnter = {};

            configAddPaymentsEnter.resizable = true

            configAddPaymentsEnter.sortable = true;

            configAddPaymentsEnter.navigatable = true;

            configAddPaymentsEnter.pageable = false;
            //{
            //  input: true,
            //  numeric: false
            //   };
            configAddPaymentsEnter.editable = 
            {
             createAt : 'bottom'
            };

           // configAddPaymentsEnter.addParams = { position: "last" };
            configAddPaymentsEnter.columns = [

                    {
                        field: "ConnectionReference",
                        attributes: {
                            "navi-text": ""
                        },
                        headerTemplate: 'Connection Reference',
                        template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" type ="text"   ng-model="dataItem.ConnectionReference"  class="k-fill text-right aa" format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                        width: "130px"
                         , aggregates: ["count"], footerTemplate: "No of Records: #=count-1#"
                    },
                     {
                         field: "ContractNumber",
                         attributes: {
                             "navi-text": ""
                         },
                         headerTemplate: 'Contract Number',
                         template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" type ="text"   class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.ContractNumber"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                         width: "130px"
                     },
                      {
                          field: "Amount",
                          attributes: {
                              "navi-text": ""
                          },
                          headerTemplate: 'Amount',
                          template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" kendo-numeric-text-box type ="text"  class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.Amount" format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                          width: "130px"
                           , aggregates: ["sum"], //footerTemplate: function (s1) { return "Total Amount: " + s1["dataItem.Amount"].sum; }
                          footerTemplate: "Total Amount: #=+sum#"

                      },
                      {
                          field: "ReferenceNumber",
                          attributes: {
                              "navi-text": ""
                          },
                          headerTemplate: 'Reference Number',
                          template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)"  type ="text"    class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.ReferenceNumber"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                          width: "130px"
                      }
                      //,
                      //{
                      //    field: "RowIndex",
                      //    attributes: {
                      //        "navi-text": ""
                      //    },
                      //    headerTemplate: 'RowIndex',
                      //    template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)"  type ="text"    class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.RowIndex"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                      //    width: "130px"
                      //}
            ];


            configAddPaymentsEnter.scrollable = true;

           

            configAddPaymentsEnter.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [s1],
               
                aggregate: [{ field: "ConnectionReference", aggregate: "count" },
                              { field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }], 
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {

                            'ConnectionReference': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            'ContractNumber': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            'Amount': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            'ReferenceNumber': { editable: true, type: "number" }
                            //,
                           // 'RowIndex': { editable: false, type: "number" }

                          
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5000,

            });

            
          

            $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter = new DataGrid();
            $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.options(configAddPaymentsEnter);

            $scope.Init = function (arg) {
                $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.Init(arg);
            };
            $scope.Init = function (arg) {
                $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.Init(arg);
            };

            $scope.submitForm = function () {
               
               // var fun = $scope.callback();
              //  var d = $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data();
              //  d.splice(0, 1);
              //  fun($scope.params.Qty, $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data());
                
            }
         
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            $scope.AA = function (row, e) {
                var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
                if (key === 13) {
                    var focusedElement = $(e.target);

                    // var nextElement = focusedElement.parent().next();
                    var nextElement = focusedElement.closest('td').next();

                    //if (nextElement[0] == undefined) {
                    //   // s1.push({ 'ConnectionReference': '1', 'ContractNumber': '2', 'Amount': '3', 'ReferenceNumber': '4' });
                    //    var nextElement = focusedElement.closest('tr').next().children().eq(0);//next row's first column;
                    //    nextElement.find('input').focus();

                    //}


                    if (nextElement.find('input').length > 0) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            nextElement.find('input').focus();
                        }, 10);


                    } else if ((nextElement.next().length) == 0) {
                        //  if ($(e.target).closest('td').is(':last-child') && $(e.target).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {


                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var index = 0;
                            $('.aa').eq(index).focus();

                            // var firstRow = $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.tbody.find('tr:first');

                        }, 10);

                     //   var s1 = [];
                        s1 = $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data();
                        $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data([]);
                        var s = row.dataItem;


                        //  var rowCounter = s1.length;

                       // console.log(rowCounter);

                        //s1.push({ 'ConnectionReference': '', 'ContractNumber': '', 'Amount': '', 'ReferenceNumber': '' });
                        s1.push({ 'ConnectionReference': s.ConnectionReference, 'ContractNumber': s.ContractNumber, 'Amount': s.Amount, 'ReferenceNumber': s.ReferenceNumber });


                        $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data(s1);
                        // var addGrid = $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.data()


                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

   <div id="dgAddPaymentsEnterId" tabindex="0"
                                             kendo-grid="dgAddPaymentsEnter1"
                                             ng-init="Init('dgAddPaymentsEnterId')"
                                             k-options="dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.options()">
                                        </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkyxb.png
[the sample ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkyxb.png)

i use kendo grid for a data entry form. it have a grid with four columns. a single row have four input text boxes (one for each column ) for data entry. 
the first time the grid load it should have a single row with four inputs, with the cursor focused to first input.
when user enter some data and press 'enter' key, the focus should move to next cell input in the same row.
when you press enter in the last column input, a new row should be added to the grid and the data entered should be saved on the grid. focus should go to new row's first input. all cells should be editable and navigatable with enter key.

Can some one please give me a solution for this in angularjs/ javascript? Im using angularjs with kendo grid.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you'll probably want to include some sample code to show generally what you've tried so far and which part in particular you are stuck on.  You can either use the code editor built into SO or a third party one like plnkr or codepen so long as you include the relevant code snippets in your question (or an answer).  Regarding your question since it is to do with DOM manipulation you'll want a directive, perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field

Comment: One more comment.  Keep in mind this is really atypical behavior for navigating a screen, typically tab is used to switch between boxes and enter is used to confirm/save an entry (at least on the web).

Comment: i edit my first post and included the grid code. pls take a look at it and help me out. thanks

Comment: in this code i have declared an empty array and i have bound data source of the grid to this empty array. this always load a empty row with undefined data-uid at the top of the grid. and other data rows display below it as i push data to the s1 array. i want the empty row at the end of the array, not at top. but i can not use array unshift() method since it adds new data from bottom to top. i want the data to be added from top to bottom while keeping the empty data entry row as the last row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible. But its hard to write the full code here, I don't think there is a direct way from Angular or Kendo UI to do this ( some one can correct me if im wrong ) , you will have to combine different technologies in this case. You can look in to DOM Manipulation to include the needed input fields dynamically after each entry and AngularJS for data bindings