# Search input field is blocking on Android (website)

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-layout

Minor bug I'm trying to fix on Android devices accessing a site.
Flow goes like this:
User inputs text, list returns answers.
User clicks li element, is scrolled to the next page (ng Anchorscroll).
User is then at the top of next page, and can enter next input.

This is fine on iOS and web, but the keyboard is blocking on Android.
I hope this doesn't violate SO terms, but here is a video of the problem with my web app (I won't upload the code).
https://youtu.be/YwXRV_APMOQ

I have tried using conditions such as ‚ "if Android`document.activeElement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();`
On resize `$(input).focus();`, and even `onclick="window.location.href="#destination"`

But none are working.
Looking for some sort of work around or help, thanks! :)

Comment: It is very confusing to figure out how it should be working. Can you post an iOS video too where it is working as intended?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOxTB5DrhAg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around. On click, focus on the next input. This pulls the input into the screen on Android, which is the behaviour needed.

(I've used Angular method, but can you any language)
[How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)