# Focusing input filed is going below header

Tags: angularjs

I have a long form and i am trying to focus the invalid fields with focus.
I have a fixed header, so focusing input field is going below the header.
Anyway to fix it?

I am using angular 1.5.7, ng-bootstrap, slimscroll in site.

Comment: You can do focus manually, adding header hight to scroll. Well, I'm not sure, but you can also use ng-focus on elements and do manual scroll on header height in ng-focus function.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a directive which will handle this functionality. You can refer below stackoverflow link, which worked for me, illustrating how you can create the custom directive to set the focus.

[How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

Here is plunker for my comment

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ajoi66vkzsbxoiokLD93?p=preview

```
<input ng-focus="tc.onFocus()" type="text" />

vm.onFocus = function(){
    var height = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].offsetHeight; 
    document.scrollHeight -= height;
}
```

Here is the main idea.

And btw, there is a good practice to add `padding-top: fixed header height` to container after header.