# Angular CRUD -- How to auto focus to the textbox?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a CRUD inline edit/add using AngularJS. I would like to know how to auto-focus to the textbox on Edit/New.

The textboxes are dynamically created within the modal window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing an attribute directive would be best idea. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/dd407b93ed288d499778) is the link you can simply use this.

Answer (score 1):

Write your custom directive or you can use https://github.com/Aks1357/angular-auto-focus, it has bower option