# Is there any way I can direct focus to a specific input field on a form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a large form and I would like when the user clicks a "new" button for the focus to be placed in a specific input field. There's a grid on the form and every field has a known id. Note it might not be the first field so not easy to use the tab.

Would appreciate some advice if this is possible. Would save having to manually have the user move the cursor over and click in the input field.

Update: Changed "move cursor" to "change focus"

Comment: you can use `focus` event

Comment: Just curious why you think it's better UX to move the user's mouse for them.  That's really jarring and disorienting.  I'd suggest an alternative approach, like just focusing as pwolaq suggests.

Comment: yes your correct. I would like to use the focus event but not quite sure how to do this. Thanks

Comment: You need a directive for that, so you can track focus status. This answer of mine to different question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17739731/158523

Comment: Good link about angularJS input field focus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution -

Angular js gives you an advantage of using some of the extra features so that you dont have to use the jquery.

Here is one way to implement the **autofocus** feature.

```
<div class="button" input-focus>{{element.idORname}}</div>
```

and the **directive** to be defined here.

```
.directive("inputfocus",function($timeout){
           return {
                    link : function(element,attributes){
                    element.bind('click',function($timeout){
                       $timeout(function(){
                          element/*.parent() or.child()*/.find('type of the field you want to select')[0].focus();
                          );
                        );
                      );
```

Here you can use the `javascript` or `jquery` methods for the `dom` traversal if there are `nested` fields in your code.

$timeout is necessary to call for the focus after the browser renders when user  has finished clicking the event

As you can see the `find('')[0]` is a replacement for `find('').focus` as the latter requires `jquery` to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Place "autofocus" attribute on the element that you want to focus.

Example:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the input ids are known, just use that.

```
$("#NewButton").on('click', function(){
    //Other code.
    $("#IdOfInputToBeFocused").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom data attribute can be used with jQuery like this

`<input data-field="special" />`

And then that specific field can be called like this

`jQuery('input').find("[data-field='special']").focus();`