# Angular UI Bootstrap loses focus of field after selecting date

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

After user selects the date, I want to focus to stay on the calendar input field. 
Currently, the focus will stay if the user selects "Today" "Clear" or "Close" but not if they select a date.

I found a solution detailing passing in $event to the function on ng-click, and then using `$event.preventDefault();` and `$event.stopPropagation();` 
You can see the solution working here: [Plunker Solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJyF531w0QRGiAScRf15?p=preview) from [Johnny Reilly's blog post](http://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2015/05/angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-weirdness.html)

However, when applied to the current versions, it is not working. 
My attempt to apply the solution here: [Angular UI Bootstrap Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nOcvDDt2anD6TGjx4LWC?p=preview)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field

Comment: @svarog here is my attempt at that solution (not working): https://plnkr.co/edit/oXxBYBWBbs8zM6XYy0Ut?p=preview. I'd prefer to do it with less baggage. Preferably whatever the "Today" "Clear" and "Close" buttons are doing