# Set an input focus active after toggle ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I don't get how I can focus the input after it appears with ng-show / ng-hide. I'm using a button with `ng-click="showme=!showme"` to show and hide my input. Any tips?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">  
  <button ng-click="showme=!showme">SHOW/HIDE</button> 
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <input ng-show="showme" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div> 
</div>
```

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t766muL8/)

I tryed using what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field), but it doesn't work.

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t766muL8/1/)

I also tryed the autofocus directive, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: this looks like it's working just fine;  what's your question, exactly?

Comment: I would like to focus the input when it appears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Comment: No, I already tryed that but it doesn't work on my toggle function

Comment: you didn't say that, or show it here.  If you tried something that didn't work, you should describe how you tried to use it here, and possibly also update your fiddle example.

Comment: I updated the JFiddle, maybe I did something wrong, I'm new to angular

Comment: @Claies any tips on how to do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this adding a controller in which I declare a new scope and an a toggling on the attribute that declares the focus.
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="pippo" ng-controller="pippoctrl">  
  <button ng-click="showme=!showme;shouldBeOpen=!shouldBeOpen">SHOW/HIDE</button> 
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <input focus-me="shouldBeOpen" ng-show="showme" type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app=angular.module("pippo",[]);
app.controller('pippoctrl', ['$scope',function ($scope){ 
        $scope.shouldBeOpen=false;
}]);
app.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout' , function ($timeout) {
    return {
    //scope: true,   // optionally create a child scope
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('focus-me=', attrs.focusMe);
            scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe,function(value){
                console.log('value=', value);
                if (value === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });

                }
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the full code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t766muL8/24/)