# AngularJS: Set textbox auto focus

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular. I need to set focus on textbox. I searched the web and found a sample from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295416/6188148

The code I found is bit harder to understand and I copy those code in JS Fiddle but code is not running. JS Fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/099Lbgqn/1/

### Full code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="text" focus-on="focusMe"/>
</div>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, focus) {
    focus('focusMe');
});

app.directive('focusOn', function() {
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {
      //alert(name+' '+attr.focusOn);
      //alert(elem);
        if(name === attr.focusOn) {
          elem[0].focus();
        }
      });
   };
});

app.factory('focus', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return function(name) {
  //alert(name);
    $timeout(function (){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', name);
    });
  }
});
```

Few areas of the above code is not clear.

1) what is scope.$on and what it does ? `scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {}`

2) `if(name === attr.focusOn)`
No variable is there called name, so how could we refer something called name in code ?

3) see these below line

```
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {
      //alert(name+' '+attr.focusOn);
      //alert(elem);
        if(name === attr.focusOn) {
          elem[0].focus();
        }
      });
   };
```

Directive has `return function` statement, what is it? Is it immediate function ?

Why `scope.$on` has been declare with in return function ?

Would you tell me why my JS Fiddle link is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is somehow broad, I'll answer you point by point.

first of all, the jsfiddle works fine and after running you will see the textbox been focued.

then, for your question:

> 1) what is scope.$on and what it does ? scope.$on('focusOn', function(e, name) {}

In angular, we use `$scope.on` to trigger events. Here it's triggering event named `focusOn`.

> 2) if(name === attr.focusOn) no variable is there called name...so how could we refere something called name in code ?

`name` is the parameter of event `focusOn` which is broadcasted by factory `focus`

> 3) directive has return function statement...what it is ? is it immediate function ?

see angular's documentation of [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

---

- the controller called factory(service) `focus`, and event `focusOn` will be broadcasted by  factory `focus`.
- the directive `focusOn` is triggering event `focusOn`, once the event is broadcasted, the textbox will be focused by this line: `elem[0].focus();`.

Comment: `$scope.on` does not trigger events. it subscribe to the events that fired by emit or broadcast

Comment: when i check the jsfiddle link by chrome browser then i saw it is working.

Comment: what is the meaning of return function in directives with in which scope.on has been declared ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar return function of  directive is the way angular dealing with custom directives. and scope.$on is built-in in angularjs framework.