# How to set a focus on text box by Dynamically using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

It could be done by,

```
 angular.element($("#Id").focus());
```

Is there any way to set them using **ng-model** attribute.

Comment: You can use `autofocus` attribute to the input element

Comment: You can create a directive for this as stated in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field)

Comment: I have multiple Textboxes..when condition changing dynamically while set focus to those controls..Textboxes are statics..all having Unique ng-model names..