# AngularJS: Two way data binding fails if element has ngModel and a custom directive

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made two directives to setup custom error messages in AngularJS:

errors -> displays the error messages for a form

error-message -> sets up a custom error message on an input

For some reason whenever I add the `error-message` directive to the element the ng-model binding no longer works (but validation does).

See here http://jsfiddle.net/apohl/A8Vgk/111/

Help please :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope

Comment: I so appreciate the fact that your title perfectly matched my google search; thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `errorMessage` directive uses an isolate scope. Isolate scopes affect *the entire element*, so the `ngModel` directive was being evaluated in an isolate scope - which obviously can't work - the model is on the parent scope.

I'm not sure why you established an isolate scope here. Since you are trying to create a component that **must** interact with other directives, an isolate scope is not the best choice. Since `errorMessage` doesn't affect the current scope, you may not need any defined scope, but you could use a child scope if you so chose.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14914213/259038) to read more about when to use each type of scope on a directive.